# Keyboard not showing after editing some fields

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard

we have a very strange problem with the IOS keyboard. We have 2 view controllers with 2 textfields in the first one and a `UISearchbar` in the second one.

If we don't edit any textfield we are able to show the keyboard in each textfield and searchbar on both viewcontrollers, however when we edit one of them we lose the possibility of showing the keyboard, even when the delegate function shouldBeginEditing is launched... had you had a similar problem?? It is like a bug with hiding the keyboard...

When we dismiss both ViewControllers the keyboard starts working again. When we check the first responder and it is nil and the windows are the following:

> 2016-05-10 09:27:11.722 Nepcom[1352:1777156] isKeyWindow = 1 window
>   level = 0.0 frame = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} class = UIWindow 2016-05-10
>   09:27:11.723 Nepcom[1352:1777156] isKeyWindow = 0 window level = 1.0
>   frame = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} class = UITextEffectsWindow 2016-05-10
>   09:27:11.723 Nepcom[1352:1777156] isKeyWindow = 0 window level =
>   2100.0 frame = {{0, 0}, {375, 667}} class = UITextEffectsWindow

We don't know what to do.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: just add keyboard notification method and check that is called or not

Comment: it is not called... we have the notification already observed

Answer (score 0):

> First, it may be because the keyboard is covered by a higher-level window (see windowLevel for more information). In iOS, the keyboard is a subview of an independent window. The window has a higher level than the application's key window, so it is always displayed in the front. If you create another window in the overlapped position and make its level higher than that of the keyboard window, then the keyboard would be covered, thus becoming invisible to your users. You can confirm this by checking the relevant attributes of your application window

from

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1813/_index.html

Comment: In this case the first responder would be nil? On the other hand we are not creating any other window... if we don't edit the content of the textfields of the first viewcontroller the keyboard is showing propperly

Comment: your first responder should not be nil . see your delegate methods of textfield  and also  frame of both view controller's view

Comment: Your text input view refuses to become the first responder. This may happen when the - (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder method of your view class returns NO. If you override this method for some reasons, be sure that it returns YES when the text input view is interactive.

Comment: The field is a normal UISearchBar I have not overrided the becomeFirstResponer method... and as I commented the shouldBeginEditing is returning YES

Comment: can you please test same in ios 7 or 8

Comment: I think the problem is not about the level of the window, but i'll try on the simulator with IOS8

Comment: There is not error, we just don't see the keyboard. We create the window log to see all the windows shown. IOS8 is having same behaviour